AWS EKS: error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

I'm having trouble accessing my AWS EKS cluster using kubectl. I keep encountering the following error:
E1017 14:53:35.073272   19400 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1017 14:53:37.144898   19400 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1017 14:53:39.207462   19400 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1017 14:53:41.371698   19400 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
E1017 14:53:43.469213   19400 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Context:
I created my EKS cluster using eksctl with the following command:
eksctl create cluster --name <cluster-name> --region us-east-1


I have an AWS account and created an EKS cluster successfully.
I'm using the admin user with AdministratorAccess policy attached.
I've run the following command to update my kubeconfig:

aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster-name> --region <region> --profile <profile-name>

Steps I've Taken:

Verified IAM Role and Permissions:

My admin user has AdministratorAccess, so it should have the necessary permissions for EKS operations.
I confirmed that the user is correctly set up by running:

aws sts get-caller-identity

Output:
{
    "UserId": "AIDAVWIBBMAWEDUDUNGE2",
    "Account": "391381082156",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::391381082156:user/admin"
}


Updated kubeconfig:

After running the aws eks update-kubeconfig command, I checked the kubeconfig file at C:\Users\xxx\.kube\config, but I still receive the authentication error when I attempt to run:

kubectl --kubeconfig C:\Users\x\.kube\config get nodes

The output was:
E1017 14:49:50.991058   33324 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials



Questions:

How can I ensure my admin user has the appropriate permissions to access the EKS cluster?
What steps should I take to modify the aws-auth ConfigMap to grant access?
Are there any other permissions or configurations I might be missing?

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials error: You must be logged in to the server
I have tried everything on this but I don't know what to do anymore
The weirdest thing is,
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-136-56-14 ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-192-168-22-51.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   72m   v1.30.4-eks-a737599
ip-192-168-57-66.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   72m   v1.30.4-eks-a737599
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-136-56-14 ~]$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AIDAVWIBBMAWEDUDUNGE2",
    "Account": "391381082156",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::391381082156:user/admin"
}
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-136-56-14 ~]$ 

IT WORKS IN THE CLOUDSHELL WITH THE SAME USER.
